# How do I customize Publish Item Panel?

Tags: content-editor

I would like to customize the publish panel. Say I have to customize the language names

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/UBHMHzhZl]

Can some one please share the XML file path ?

Answer (score 4):

I do not recommend to change this form, it's better to educate editors to use it as it is.

But if you still want to change this Dialog form you need to do :

1.
  Code beside for this Dialog is this class :  `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm,Sitecore.Client`. You 
 need to use Reflector, DotPeek or IlSpy to decompile the code, and create your custom class according to your requirements.

2.You neeed to change BuildLanguages method.

3.Compile your class and deploy it.

4.Go to

`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourproject\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish\` and edit the file **Publish.xml** . Change the **Codebeside** value from next line :

```
 <WizardForm CodeBeside="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm,Sitecore.Client">
```

with your custom class.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can add the new xml to the override folder instead of overwriting the existing file